# i get cannot " 'node.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: node.js, angular, windows

I'm setting up a new server, but I get a node error while using  node start 
    command

```
I'm trying to create a server for angular 2 and use a database with it 
(PostgreSQL)



server.js

    var express=require('express');
    var app=new express();
    var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
    var db=require('../DATABASE/database');

    db.sync().then(function(){
    app.listen(3000,function () {
    console.log('It works');
    })
    })

database.js

var Sequelize=required('sequelize');

var sequelize=new Sequelize('../SQL',{
dialect:'postgres',
database: 'NEW1',
username: 'postgres',
password: 'yasik239@',
host: 'localhost',
dialectOptions:{
    SSL:{
        required:true
    }
}
});

module.exports=sequelize;

table.sql

CREATE TABLE paradox(
id                  serial,
username            varchar NOT NULL,
user_password       varchar NOT NULL,
email               varchar NOT NULL,
first_name          varchar,
last_name           varchar,
display_name        varchar,
user_location       varchar,
bio                 text,

PRIMARY KEY(id),

)

package.json
```

{
    "name": "name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node./SERVER/server"
    },

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "json-web-token": "^3.1.1",
    "pg": "^7.12.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelizer": "^1.1.3"
}
```

}

Error shown is

'node.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! name@0.0.1 start: `node./SERVER/server`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the name@0.0.1 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-08T06_11_25_492Z-debug.log

```
I expect the output of getting the server running, but the actual output 
is not running”

"node.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
```

My logfile

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'start' ]

2 info using npm@6.9.0

3 info using node@v10.16.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle name@0.0.1~prestart: name@0.0.1

6 info lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: name@0.0.1

7 verbose lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: PATH: C:\Program Files 
(x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\MY

FOLDER\node_modules.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm

9 verbose lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: CWD: E:\IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\MY FOLDER

10 silly lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node./SERVER/server' ]

11 silly lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle name@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script

13 verbose stack Error: name@0.0.1 start: `node./SERVER/server`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files 
(x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)

13 verbose stack     at may be close (internal/child_process.js:982:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

14 verbose pkgid name@0.0.1

15 verbose cwd E:\IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\MY FOLDER

16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601

17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files
 (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v10.16.0

19 verbose npm  v6.9.0

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error name@0.0.1 start: `node./SERVER/server`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the name@0.0.1 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: can u share your package.json file? and whats the command you are using to run the node server?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./SERVER/server"
    }
}
```

in your package.json file, you haven't left a space after "node" keyword in the start script. Correct your "scripts" like above that should work. IF you encounter errors again do not hesitate to let us know

Comment: options.dialect = urlParts.protocol.replace(/:$/, '');
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null       



This error persists.What to do?

Thanks

Comment: options.dialect = urlParts.protocol.replace(/:$/, ''); 
is this line included in your server.js file if so please share your entire server.js file in your question above